# Mock - make a spy class method return a specific value

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I'm running some unit tests on a `methodA` of a spied instance of a class (let's say instance is myClass), which uses a helper method (lets call it `helper(long num, ObjectA obA, ObjectB obB)`) to determine the boolean value of a flag

The parameters of this class are all mocked, the class is instantiated with a `spy` call, and the method itself is a protected method with 3 parameters. The method is called with every run of `methodA`. MethodA sets the values of the parameters for the helper method

My question is, is there a way to make, in this specific test, the `helper` method return true?

I've tried to, using the following:

```
when(myClass.shouldSetFlag(anyLong(), any(ObjectA.class), any(ObjectB.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

but every time I get a null pointer exception.

Would really appreciate some insight, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you've provided only one line of code and no stack trace, I assume the NullPointerException is thrown from the `shouldSetFlag` method.

When you mock the method using `when(...)` Mockito actually replaces the matchers with default values during the method call in this line (it's still Java code, the method is still called). If you act on ObjectA or ObjectB instances inside the method, the actual code encounters a `null` reference and the exception is thrown.

From [the docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html):

> Matcher methods like anyObject(), eq() do not return matchers. Internally, they record a matcher on a stack and return a dummy value (usually null).

You can also observe that in [the Mockito code, since it's open source](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/v4.6.1/src/main/java/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.java).

To work around that use `doReturn(...)` (see the docs [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html)) - the actual method will not be called while mocking, yet it still will be registered in Mockito.